# setting up afterpay with shopify product page - not showing

Tags: javascript, shopify

I've added the shopify code to my theme.liquid but it is not showing up anywhere on the product page, if anyone could help that'd be great

My Website: https://monoporium.com.au/collections/men/products/unisex-sweatshirt-1?variant=33080260690055

My Code:

```html
<!-- Begin Shopify-Afterpay JavaScript Snippet (v1.0.5) -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Editable fields:
    var afterpay_min = 0.04;            // As per your Afterpay contract.
    var afterpay_max = 1000.00;         // As per your Afterpay contract.
    var afterpay_cbt_enabled = false;   // As per your Afterpay contract; change to true to display Cross-Border Trade artwork (for AU/NZ).
    var afterpay_logo_theme = 'colour'; // Can be 'colour', 'black' or 'white'.

    // Non-editable fields:
    var afterpay_shop_currency = {{ shop.currency | json }};
    var afterpay_cart_currency = {{ cart.currency.iso_code | json }};
    var afterpay_shop_money_format = {{ shop.money_format | json }};
    var afterpay_shop_permanent_domain = {{ shop.permanent_domain | json }};
    var afterpay_theme_name = {{ theme.name | json }};
    var afterpay_product = {{ product | json }};
    var afterpay_current_variant = {{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant | json }};
    var afterpay_cart_total_price = {{ cart.total_price | json }};
    var afterpay_js_snippet_version = '1.0.5';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.afterpay.com/shopify-afterpay-javascript.js"></script>
<!-- End Shopify-Afterpay JavaScript Snippet (v1.0.5) -->
```

Comment: any errors in the browser developer tools console?

Comment: https://pastecode.xyz/view/9ddbada8 this is my console

Comment: well, fix those errors - none of those errors look like they come from the code you posted, so the error is "somewhere else", and only you have the code

Comment: I'm not sure how to exactly fix these errors, one is from an app that I no longer have installed

Comment: fixed all errors and still not showing up

Answer (score 0):

To show up on Product page, Afterpay needs information about the price selector. Q quick look at Afterpay JavaScript file shows that it has a relevant object based on theme names and their relevant product price selectors. If it is not available, you can override it via your Afterpay snippet. To do so make use of

> afterpay_product_selector

Doing so your code will be

```html
<!-- Begin Shopify-Afterpay JavaScript Snippet (v1.0.5) -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Editable fields:
    var afterpay_min = 0.04;            // As per your Afterpay contract.
    var afterpay_max = 1000.00;         // As per your Afterpay contract.
    var afterpay_cbt_enabled = false;   // As per your Afterpay contract; change to true to display Cross-Border Trade artwork (for AU/NZ).
    var afterpay_logo_theme = 'colour'; // Can be 'colour', 'black' or 'white'.

    // Overrides:
    var afterpay_product_selector = '.product-page-info__price';

    // Non-editable fields:
    var afterpay_shop_currency = {{ shop.currency | json }};
    var afterpay_cart_currency = {{ cart.currency.iso_code | json }};
    var afterpay_shop_money_format = {{ shop.money_format | json }};
    var afterpay_shop_permanent_domain = {{ shop.permanent_domain | json }};
    var afterpay_theme_name = {{ theme.name | json }};
    var afterpay_product = {{ product | json }};
    var afterpay_current_variant = {{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant | json }};
    var afterpay_cart_total_price = {{ cart.total_price | json }};
    var afterpay_js_snippet_version = '1.0.5';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.afterpay.com/shopify-afterpay-javascript.js"></script>
<!-- End Shopify-Afterpay JavaScript Snippet (v1.0.5) -->
```

If the above code does not work exactly, try adjusting the price selector.
More information about [Afterpay JS Snippet](https://afterpay-online.readme.io/docs/shopify-aunz-afterpay-product-page-display)

Comment: just tried this with no luck, what do you mean by adjusting the price selector? what should i change it to?

Comment: Price selector means, the CSS selector where price is displayed on your page.
Try it with something like .price span or .product-page-info__price .price

Or just give an HTML ID to price selector and add that in your snippet.

Comment: i will give it a go, how would i set up a html id to the price selector? i'm not too familiar with shopify code etc

Comment: Depends on Shopify theme. It should be in some product.liquid page.

Comment: "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_price",
      "label": "Show price",
      "default": true
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_sale_price_separator",
      "label": "Show sale price separator",
      "default": false
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_sale_details",
      "label": "Show sale price details",
      "default": true
    },

Comment: Any of these have anything to do with it?